# Using Web3.js in VueJS - Error: undefined is not a constructor or null

Tags: vue.js, webpack, web3js

I'm using VueJs + Webpack and trying to get Web.js to work.

I installed web.js using npm `npm install web3 --save` and I'm trying to use it in one of my VueJS components by importing it using `import Web3 from 'web3'`.

When I load my application I get an error:

```
app.js:101191 Uncaught TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null
    at module.exports (app.js:101191)
    at module.exports (app.js:101155)
    at Object../node_modules/keccak/js.js (app.js:101140)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:200063)
...
```

My package.json looks like:

```
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        ...
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        ...
    },
    "dependencies": {
        ...
        "web3": "^1.3.6"
    }
```

Do I need to import it using webpack?